# Android studio new version BumbleBee show error when run old project in IOS Device/Simulator in Flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

It Will shows Error like this:-

```
After updating the Android studio it's throwing the error in IOS run

Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
```

It's run easily in android device and when we run through terminal its runs easily.

Comment: I also fetch this issue. You need to open your code to visual studio and try to run with its shows proper issue. I don't remember proper solution but i tried cocoa pods update or pod setup. Try like this if you don't solve then comment here

Comment: Solved this issue?

Comment: i have a similar problem, running android studio from terminal mitigates the problem, but nevertheless its a bit bothersome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895243/android-studio-does-not-find-cocoapods-in-console

Comment: I just downgrade it again and it's working. The issue is with the Bumble Bee version @RaviLimbani

Comment: @SheetalGhori Yes its new android studio version issue but if you want to work with new version then which solution i suggest its perfect work.

Comment: I already did the pod re-installation, setup, and update but it's not working for me. @RaviLimbani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade with the new version of Bumblebee resolve the issue for me

**Version**: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I am hoping they will fix it soon. But, running    flutter run       from the terminal window inside Android Studio works fine and I can build and deploy for Android and iOS devices. Not a great solution, but works for now.